# run custom php code from phtml templates - magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery, phtml, static-block

I have phtml template (Magento_theme) contain   tag I want insert my custom php code ( connect database, fetch table, if condition ) into script .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not recommended answer but if you are lazy same as me than you can use below code to run raw SQL.

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from(
                ['ce' => 'salesrule'],
                ['group_members', 'range_for_individual_purchase']
            )
            ->where('rule_id =?',$nw->getRuleId());
        $data = $connection->fetchAll($select);

        echo $total_rows = count($data); exit; // updated
```

**Note** : You can also replace **$select** with MySQl query.
Hope it will help you.

**Its not recommended**, You have to define Model than fetch Data whatever you want in phtml file.

Hope it will help you !!

Comment: I already try this method before and connection sucsess but what about another part of code (if condition ex)

Comment: @Mage67, Where you wan to implement **if condition**, ? Please  update answer with your code and what you are trying to achieve so that i can guide you.

Comment: Check updated answer ! I think later on you can do stuff yourself !!

Comment: ?? I Can't check updated answer . U already update it?

Comment: Check my comment, I think you just looking for replace of **mysql_num_rows** in Magento

Comment: U check php code in screenshot?

Comment: No I want calculate js counter time with custom php code.

Comment: U have Any idea to insert php code into phtml

Comment: You can use same as basic PHP code, No Rocket science in it.

Comment: U mean only connect with data base with method u share and insert my. Custom php .

Comment: from(
                ['ce' => 'salesrule'],
                can I get explain about thisline

Comment: @Mage67, Yes, That's it, Than you can convert your code in PHP. phtml is same as html file , In it you can right HTML and PHP .

Comment: 'ce' is just constant you can use whatever you want. salesrule is table name. You can replace it with your table.

Comment: Great ['group_members', 'range_for_individual_purchase']
            )
            ->where('rule_id =?',$nw->getRuleId());

Comment: It's name for field from your table You can replace it with your fields. I just need 2 fields so i added, If you require all fields than you can remove that line. Than it will gives you all fields in select.